# type error "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript

Im new to programming in javascript and keep getting a "undefined is not a function" type error. This program is for Project Euler [Problem 4](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4). Thanks for the help in advance.'

```
var biggestNumber = 0;
var q = '';
var x = 1;
for (var i = 100; i < 1000; i ++) {
    var y = i -1;
    var z = y*i;
    for (var s = 0;s <= (z.length);s++ ){
        if (str(z)[s] === (str(z)((length.x)-s))){
            q.append('1');
        }
        else{
            q.append('0');
        }
    }
    if (q.index('0') === -1){
        q = q;
    }
    else{
        q = z;
    }
    if (z > biggestNumber){
        biggestNumber = z;
    }
}
console.log(biggestNumber);
```

Comment: Press F12 to open your console. Click on the error, and navigate to the line within your code where the error is occuring. That information would be very helpful to those of us who are trying to help you.

Comment: The error in the console is "TypeError: q.index is not a function `if (q.index('0') === -1){`" . . . Yuriy Galanter's answer below is the right one.

Answer (score 2):

In your inner for loop you try to execute "str" as a function with parameters "z":

```
for (var s = 0;s <= (z.length);s++ ){
    if (str(z)[s] === (str(z)((length.x)-s))){
        q.append('1');
}
```

The variable "str" is not defined anywhere in your script above. That's most likely where the error is generated from. You're either missing some code, or did a copy/paste/spelling mistake.

In fact, this whole line is messed up:

```
(str(z)[s] === (str(z)((length.x)-s)))
```

Without more context, it's impossible to answer your question or help you further.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `index` it's `indexOf`.

Instead of

```
if (q.index('0') === -1){
```

do

```
if (q.indexOf('0') === -1){
```